# Declaring a generic utility function above a React component vs declaring the function as part of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between declaring a function above a React component vs declaring the function as part of the component.

Having `getDisplayOptions` in the component itself.

```
class PageShoppingChannel extends React.Component {
  getDisplayOptions = (providers) => {
    const options = []
    const { isFaeSet } = this.props

    providers.forEach((item) => {
      // code here 
    })
    return options
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <TempIllsWithInfo illsType='Orders [Red]' infoBloc={infoBlock} />
        <hr className='row-spacing--sm' />
        {this.getDisplayOptions(this.props.providers)}
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

Having `getDisplayOptions` before the component.

```
getDisplayOptions = (providers) => {
  const options = []

  providers.forEach((item) => {
      // code here 
  })
  return options
}

class PageShoppingChannel extends React.Component {
  


  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <TempIllsWithInfo illsType='Orders [Red]' infoBloc={infoBlock} />
        <hr className='row-spacing--sm' />
        {getDisplayOptions(this.props.providers)}
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

I believe in the former case the function gets attached to the `prototype` of `PageShoppingChannels`. What are the advantages and disadvantages of the both these approaches. I believe this is a javascript question , but my example was in react so forgive me for conflating the two here.

Comment: The second approach doesn't seem valid, I think you're missing something. Not sure where you've seen this pattern before, but this doesn't seem like a "generic function" since it's trying to access `this.props` inside of its body, so this looks to me like it should be a method of a component rather than a "generic function."

Comment: @goto1 my bad the 2nd example actually does't contain ```this.props```, correction made.

Comment: So ultimately the question is, do you need a reusable function that you can use across different components or do you need a method that will be used only for a specific component.

Comment: @goto1 , no not really , the question is what is the difference between declaring a function inside a component vs declaring it outside the component but in the same file.

Comment: The difference is one is a function (outside of the component) and the other one is a method (inside of the component). If you're looking for a "what is the best approach," the answer is it doesn't matter, but if this function is going to be used only within a component, then it'd make sense to turn it into a method of that said component.

Comment: @goto1 makes sense thanks. I'am not looking for a 'best approach' answer. but are there any advantages to declaring a function outside the component ? etc.

Comment: The advantage would be if you have multiple components inside of the same file and you're trying to create a reusable utility function, then you won't have to repeat your code. Other than that, I don't see any advantages or disadvantages. From the code readability perspective, you'd want to keep related things as close as possible to each other, i.e. if you have a method called `methodA` that calls `methodB`, I'd expect `methodB` to come right after `methodA` so that it "reads like a book" and things are easier & faster to find, instead of searching for it somewhere outside of the component.

Comment: @goto1 alrighty , you could add that as an answer :) TY for the explanation.